# Remove observations from DF if duplicate in specific columns while other columns must differ

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a large data frame with multiple columns and many rows (200k). I order the rows by a group variable, and each group can have one or more entries. The other columns for each group should have identical values, however in some cases they don't. It looks like this:

```
group   name    age    color    city
1       Anton   50     orange   NY
1       Anton   21     red      NY
1       Anton   21     red      NJ
2       Martin  78     black    LA
2       Martin  78     blue     LA
3       Maria   29     red      NC
3       Maria   29     pink     LV
4       Jake    33     blue     NJ
```

I want to delete all entries of a group if age or city is not identical for all rows of the group (indication of observation error). Otherwise, I want to keep all the entries.

The output I'm hoping for would be:

```
group   name    age    color    city
2       Martin  78     black    LA
2       Martin  78     blue     LA
4       Jake    33     blue     NJ
```

The closest I have come is this:

```
dup <- df[ duplicated(df[,c("group","name","color")]) | duplicated(df[,c("group","name","color")],fromLast=TRUE)    ,"group"]
df_nodup <- df[!(df$group %in% dup),]
```

However, this is far from doing everything that I need.

P.s.: I had the same question answered for py/pandas. I'd like to have a solution for R, as well however.

/e: While Frank's answer was helpful to understand the principle of a solution and his second suggestion worked, it was very slow. (took ~15min on my df).
user20650's answer was harder to comprehend, but runs tremendously faster (~10sec).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar approach to Franks, you can count the `length` of the `unique` combinations of `age` and `city` by `group` - do this using `ave`. You can then subset your data if the length of the unique combinations is greater than one

```
# your data

df <- read.table(text="group   name    age    color    city
1       Anton   50     orange   NY
1       Anton   21     red      NY
1       Anton   21     red      NJ
2       Martin  78     black    LA
2       Martin  78     blue     LA
3       Maria   29     red      NC
3       Maria   29     pink     LV
4       Jake    33     blue     NJ ", header=T)

# calculate and subset

df[with(df, ave(paste(age, city), group, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x))))==1,]

#   group   name age color city
# 4     2 Martin  78 black   LA
# 5     2 Martin  78  blue   LA
# 8     4   Jake  33  blue   NJ
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach:

```
temp <- tapply(df$group, list(df$name, df$age, df$city), unique)  
temp[!is.na(temp)] <- 1
keepers <- names(which(apply(temp, 1, sum, na.rm=TRUE)==1))

df[df$name %in% keepers, ]
#4     2 Martin  78 black   LA
#5     2 Martin  78  blue   LA
#8     4   Jake  33  blue   NJ
```

Alternate, slightly simpler approach:

```
temp2 <- unique(df[,c('name','age','city')])
keepers2 <- names(which(tapply(temp2$name, temp2$name, length)==1))

df[df$name %in% keepers2, ]
#  group   name age color city
#4     2 Martin  78 black   LA
#5     2 Martin  78  blue   LA
#8     4   Jake  33  blue   NJ
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using dplyr:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
  group   name    age    color    city
  1       Anton   50     orange   NY
  1       Anton   21     red      NY
  1       Anton   21     red      NJ
  2       Martin  78     black    LA
  2       Martin  78     blue     LA
  3       Maria   29     red      NC
  3       Maria   29     pink     LV
  4       Jake    33     blue     NJ 
", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(age) == 1 && n_distinct(city) == 1)
```

I think it's pretty easy to see what's going on - you group, then filter to keep groups when there is only one distinct age and city.